# Can I Store Extra Info In My Python venv?

Tags: python, python-venv

What I want to do is store a reference to the project location (my source files)  in my venv.
The purpose for this is so I can automatically switch to that directory when I activate my venv.
I already have a script that managers my venvs.  e.g. `workonvenv xyz` will activate the venv named xyz.

Comment: Sounds like want to reinvent virtualenvwrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add this logic to the script that manages the venvs?
A venv is not tightly coupled with a project, meaning venvs can be used for several projects and a project doesn't necessarily need a venv to work. Therefore there's no reference of a project in the venv.

What I recommend is to define a convention for project and venv names such as - project: "project-x" and venv: "project-x-venv" and then use your script to activate the venv and then cd into the project folder according to this convention.